# Interpolating none timebased data from a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

Let's say I have 2 series in pandas of the same length, just like this:

```
s1 = [40.86, 40.8, 40.72, 40.58, 40.39, 40.13, 39.7...]
s2 = [470.24, 470.1, 470.04, 469.94, 469.62, 469.74,...]
```

These series are bound to each other as pairs of "key=>value" by series index. s1 contains "key-like" values and s2 contains "value-like" values. s1[index] => s2[index]

I create new "key-like" series s3, contains values between s1.min and s1.max, quantized by certain step (0.5 for example)

`s3 = [40.5, 40.0, 39.5, 38.0, 37.5, 37.0, 36.5, 36.0...]`

Now I want a function that gets s1 s2 s3 and returns `s4`, that should contain calculated values interpolated from s1/s2 pairs. For example, if s3[n]=40.5, s4[n] may be calculated as interpolation between pairs: s1[3]=40.58/s2[3]=469.94 and  s1[4]=40.39/s2[4]=469.62

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
s1 = pd.Series([40.86, 40.8, 40.72, 40.58, 40.39, 40.13, 39.7])
s2 = pd.Series([470.24, 470.1, 470.04, 469.94, 469.62, 469.74])

interpolation = s1.round()*s2/s1
interpolation
0    471.851199
1    472.404412
2    473.272102
3    474.803844
4    465.085417
5    468.218291
6           NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: not exactly... edited question to describe interpolation task more wise